# confused about beta weights in logistic regression

Tags: graphing-functions, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, logistic-regression

I've recently started getting into machine learning, and I saw that making a simple classifier using logistic regression was a good place to start.
I was following through [this article](https://philippmuens.com/logistic-regression-from-scratch) and got to the section just before the conclusion before I got stuck.

In the article, the author uses the equations `m = -(b1 / b2)` and `b = -(b0 / b2)`. How did they get those?

I know that the equation for the boundary line is `σ(β1x1 + ... + βnxn+b)`, but when I try plugging that in with my weights it just forms (what looks like) a straight line.

Why does `1/1+e^(mx+b)` work, but `1/1+e^(β1x1 + ... + βnxn+b)` not?

[Example of 1/1+e^(mx+b)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMiNV.png)

[Example of 1/1+e^(β1x1 + ... + βnxn+b)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFhhl.png)

I'm sorry if I seem unclear. if you want a further explanation I'm happy to give it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y = \beta_2x_2+\beta_1x_1+\beta_0$$

The boundary is at $y=0$,

$$0 = \beta_2x_2+\beta_1x_1+\beta_0$$

$$-\beta_2x_2 = \beta_1x_1+\beta_0$$

$$x_2 = \left( -\frac{\beta_1}{\beta_2}\right) x_1  - \left( \frac{\beta_0}{\beta_2}\right)$$

Hence $m = -\frac{\beta_1}{\beta_2}$ and the intercept is $-\frac{\beta_0}{\beta_2}$.

As for your plot, there can be multiple reasons:

- Make sure you optimize the parameters.
- For the independent variable, make sure the corrresponding coefficient is large.